# Review site domain: xxxxreview or xxxxreviews?

Tags: seo, domains, name, user-reviews

I am thinking to opening a local product review site where we will review all kinds of local businesses and their products and readers will be able to comment and vote.

My real confusion begins with choosing the domain. I have a domain in my mind. The domain name is something like `xxxxreview.example`.  What I can't decide whether should I go for `xxxxreview.example` or `xxxxreviews.example`. both of them are available but I can't decide whether should I go with "Review" or "Reviews" and why should I choose that one. `XXXX` is for example purpose only.

Which domain to go for and why?  Will there be any SEO difference between the 2 domains because of the nature of the website?

Comment: Why not buying both domains and redirecting one to another?

Comment: You even have the `.reviews` TLD: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/reviews.html Some may also like the `.sucks` TLD.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to agree with Patrick Mevzek's comment, "Why not buying both domains and redirecting one to another?" Whichever you use, someone is going to screw it up and enter the other one so having both is a control over user error.

Your choice of review vs reviews should be based on what you think site visitors will be searching for because it's best to align the name with user expectations. Will they come to your site to read a review on a specific business, or will they be looking for reviews of a category such as restaurants? If mostly the former, use "review". If mostly the latter, use "reviews".